# Use Class Paramater in Java Bean Validator

Tags: java, validation, javabeans

I have a class and Im using Java Bean validation and Id like to use one of the classes variables as a parameter in the validator, so if I have something that looks like.

```
    public class person{

       @NotNull
       @NotEmpty
       public int age;

       @CustomValidator(Parameter = age)
       public dateTime birthdate

    }
```

Then custom validator could use age to validate birthdate, is there a way to do this or do java beans not allow it? Ive already tried just inputting the parameter and it does not seem to like that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to implement it as a parameter in the annotation itself as that requires those values to be static - you want it to be dynamic based on the value of age.

Instead of putting the custom constraint on the *birthdate* field itself, you could put it at the class level. By doing this, you get access to all fields in the **Person** object and can do the logic to validate the birthdate based on the provided age. I tested this with a String type for *birthdate* so you will have to modify that to suit your date needs.

**BirthdateConstraint.java** -

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = BirthdateValidator.class)
public @interface BirthdateConstraint {
    String message() default "Custom error message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**BirthdateValidator.java** -

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class BirthdateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BirthdateConstraint, Person> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Person value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        int age = value.age;
        String birthdate = value.birthdate;

        // do validation logic here - return true/false     
    }
}
```

**Person.java** -

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@BirthdateConstraint
public class Person {

    @Min(value = 1) 
    public int age;

    public String birthdate;
}
```